# How do I go about simultaneously sorting a list of lists while filtering out certain values?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have an ascii file of three columns and I want to sort and filter the file based on the third column. That is, I want to arrange the third column from smallest to largest and take out all values above, say, 8.0. I know how to do both of these things if it were done directly for one list. However, I don't know how to apply the changes I made for the third column to all the columns, since each row is linked to one another.

Small side question: I have unpacked the ascii file as so:

```
f=open('textfile.dat',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split('\n')[0])

a = []
b = []
c = []    
for w in result:
    ra.append(w.split()[0])
for x in result:
    dec.append(x.split()[1])
for y in result:
    mag.append(y.split()[2])

p=0
for i in a:
    a[p] = float(i)
    p= p+1    
q=0
for j in b:
    b[q] = float(j)
    q= q+1    
r=0
for k in c:
    c[r] = float(k)
    r= r+1

test=[a,b,c]
```

Which seems unnecessarily tedious to say the least. Is there any way to do this more compactly? It's simply an ascii file with four columns. Though they are numbers, they're being read as 'str' and so I have to change it back to floats.

Sorting seems to just be using a transposer then sorting according to columns, which solves my first question.

```
tset = zip(*test)
tset.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])
sorttest = zip(*tset)
```

However, if I wanted to get rid of all the numbers in the third column above, say, 8.0, I would do something like:

```
testrange[2] = [i for i in sorttest[2] if i <= 8.0]
```

However, that only applies to one row. I can't for example, do something like

```
testrange[0] = [i*1.0 for i in sorttest[2] if i <= 8.0]
testrange[1] = [i*1.0 for i in sorttest[2] if i <= 8.0]
```

Thus, how do I go about simultaneously sorting a list of lists while filtering out certain values?

Edit:

```
Sample input:
 [5,12,3,7,90]
 [9,1,63,23,8]
 [73,11,8,2,5]

Sample output:
 [7,90,3,12]
 [23,8,63,1]
 [2,5,8,11]
```

Comment: can you give a sample input and sample output

Comment: I think it would be much simpler to remove unwanted data rows first and then sort the remaining rows, instead of trying to do it all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[5,12,3,7,90],
     [9,1,63,23,8],
     [73,11,8,2,5]]
x = np.array(x)
x = x[:, np.where(x[2] < 70)[0]]
x = x[:, np.argsort(x[2])].tolist()
```

That will give you:

> [[7, 90, 3, 12], [23, 8, 63, 1], [2, 5, 8, 11]]

Comment: I tried the above code and the `np.where` function helped tremendously. However, the `np.argsort` doesn't work in this case. In fact, it only outputs the first number in the list. Aka, in that case it outputs [[7],[23],[2]] as opposed to the output you mentioned. Instead I used the sorting method I mentioned above (test.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])) to sort instead which worked! (thought this outputted it in a list rather than an array)

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for you. When I'm running this code, the argsort returns "[2 3 1 0]", which is the how you want to sort the matrix (columnwise). The second line in the matrix after removing the first column is 11,8,2,5, so using the argsort as indices you'll get 2,5,8,11.

Answer (score -1):

So I may have missed your requirement but for each line you could make a list of the items from that line split. You will end up with list(lines) of lists(separated items of a line). You can then sort the lines by column 3 of each line. Then filter that list(of lines) by column 3s value. I have done these as separate steps but you could merge them.

```
my_data = """1.4 2.5 5.6
2.4 7.5 9.8
4.8 9.7 2.5
4.5 6.5 7.9
1.3 3.4 12.6"""

list_of_data = [line.split() for line in my_data.split("\n")]
sorted_list = sorted(list_of_data, key=lambda line: float(line[2]))
filtered_list = [line for line in sorted_list if float(line[2]) < 8.0]
for line in filtered_list:
    print(" ".join(line))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4.8 9.7 2.5
1.4 2.5 5.6
4.5 6.5 7.9
```

So th output has remove those lines where the 3rd column was 8.0 or greater. and all the related numbers from the same line are also still matchin and in the order based on 3rd column